# Android Studio can't run imported projects (Error running 'app' default activity not found

Tags: java, android

My first question on here, have tried a lot already and seems very simple however somehow not able to fix it. I have done research and know that this question has been asked a lot already, however the solutions provided don't seem to work.

Quick summary:
Following free course on Udacity for Android Developer, to follow the exercises you import a project that you downloaded from the course, you do some tasks and then run it. However I notice that on imported projects I either can't get the app to run, or can't apply changes and run, either one provides the error running 'app' default activity not found.
I have checked multiple times on projects that I created myself and that works correctly.

I can confirm default activity is setup correctly within the androidmanifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name="com.example.android.datafrominternet.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have tried changing it to .MainActivity as well, doesn't make a difference.
I have checked the launch options is set to 'default activity' however changing that doesn't resolve it. Neither does setting it to the specific Activity resulting in "Warning: the activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

I have also tried the options:

- Sync project with gradle files
- Invalidate caches/restart
- Rebuild project

I thought I had it working with the following solution:

"I had this issue on Android Studio 4.0.1, android gradle 4.0.1 build gradle 6.1.1 and could not resolve it with the answers here.

What eventually fixed it for me was going to my app folder and deleting the entire .gradle folder, then invalidating cache and restarting. Normal cache invaldiation didn't work. Rebuilding, cleaning, syncing with gradle: None of it worked without me going in and deleting the entire .gradle folder."

However the next day having the same issue again. My versions are exactly the same as mentioned in the solution above.

I still think I am missing something simple, however not sure what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, needed to upgrade gradle and then the correcting the version numbers after that use the caches/restart which resolves it for each project now.